# Add a column to a dataframe based on values from a different dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a data frame:

```
head(DF1)
                 class CH1..contrast validJT well
WG1.1 wellA1_col1_row1          17.1 invalid   A1
WG1.2 wellA1_col1_row1          16.7 invalid   B1
WG1.3 wellA1_col1_row1          14.9   valid   A2
WG1.4 wellA1_col1_row1           8.9 invalid   A3
WG1.5 wellA1_col1_row1           7.1 invalid   A1
WG1.6 wellA1_col1_row1          17.4 invalid   A1
type here
```

and I want to add a new column called "WG" based on the value in column "well" (Which can be anything from A1-3 to B1-3). In another data frame:

```
view(DF2)
  Well Sample
1   A1  HIV-1
2   A2  HIV-1
3   A3  HIV-1
4   B1    CD3
5   B2    CD3
6   B3    CD3
```

I have the information for which well number corresponds to which sample. But I have no idea where to start, so basically I want to say add a column to DF1 where if DF1$well = "A1" add the DF2$Sample from "A1" in DF2.

Is this possible, I don't even know where to start?

Comment: You need to *join* the two data frames.  There are numerous examples of how to do this on StackOverflow

Comment: `DF1 |> dplyr::left_join(DF2, join_by(well == Well))`

Comment: The base R function for that is `merge()`. E.g., https://www.infoworld.com/article/3454356/how-to-merge-data-in-r-using-r-merge-dplyr-or-datatable.html or https://r-coder.com/merge-r/#google_vignette or https://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `dplyr` package will provide `left_join` which can be used to achieve this:

```
DF1 %>%
   left_join(DF2)
```

However, one minor change will be needed. The columns need identical names for them to be recognized in the `join_by` without specifying. Both DF1 & DF2 should have either "well" or "Well" as the column names.

Comment: Hahaha very easy solution I was trying all sorts of wack things to achieve this! Thanks!